# How do I trigger a real time client update in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, websocket, real-time, server-sent-events

I'm creating an online multiplayer board game using Rails, and I want the game to be able to be played without having to manually refresh the page. I'm planning on using websockets or Server Sent Events's to update the page. I haven't decided which yet, but I don't expect it to make a difference for my question.

The thing I'm confused about is knowing when to send an update to the client. For example, let's say I was making chess, and player1 took a turn. They would send up their move to the server, the server would then save it to the database. How does player2's websocket or SSE know to push the info about player1's move to player2's brower?

I know they could regularly query the database to see if the game has been updated, but that seems like it would be hard to scale since every user would be querying the database very often.

Is there an easy way to wait for an update to the database and be notified of it automatically somehow? Or are there other solutions?

I've looked around online a bunch for solutions to this, but haven't really gotten any concrete ideas. I'm definitely open to using a library or whatever to solve the problem as long as it's free. I've seen some paid solutions but those aren't an option.

I also saw someone suggest somehow using node.js alongside rails to do something with realtime. I don't know much about node.js, but I have heard it's good for asynchronous functionality like that. I'd be interested in learning how to use it if it's better than any rails solution.

I'm using Rails 3.2, but if Rails 4 has something that would work well here, I'd probably be interested in that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As nik suggested, use the FAYE Ruby Server if you're a ruby developer.

In terms of how things could hang together:

1. Each game is a channel
2. Each player subscribes to this channel
3. When a player makes a move, the move is sent to the server
4. The server saves the move against the game in the db
5. The server sends a message to the channel.
6. Both player's ui update with the new move.

This setup allows you to easily replay a whole game or continue where you left off. Just get all moves from db and send them in order to a new channel. This might not be performant, but it should work.

Comment: FAYE seems to work using long polling or Server Sent Events. Is it possible to use it with 2 way communications such as websockets? So instead of making a separate http request for each move you make you use the same websocket to submit all of your moves?

Comment: i meant use the same websocket to submit all of your moves and also receive updates from the game channel

Comment: yes, the client connects to the FAYE server and can either send messages to the server or subscribe (receive) events from the server.

Comment: so faye would be a separate server, not my rails server right? Would I need a separate url for that server? Like if i was running my server at mychesssite.com, would faye have to be something other than mychesssite.com?

Comment: I would just like to note that if you're planning on writing the majority of the game in javascript, then perhaps rails wouldn't be the best stack (LiveController in Rails 4 is more complicated than Faye, btw). If a websocket is too big, you can have your js check every second or two for a player/ board changes. It's not a best practice, but it might be a more familiar realm until you can implement a proper websocket (Relying purely on cancan and devise + setTimeout, for example).

Comment: The main purpose of this project is to learn rails, so I'd like to stick with it. The game is also more complex than just chess, and the website as a whole will benefit from having rails I think. FAYE seems like a good solution to the problem.

Comment: I think the choice of stack partly depends on the type of game. For example, a turn based game doesn't require real time events and could be done in rails or other mvc style stacks. If you have a real time game, then things get more interesting and personally I would then go for Node. Go would be another option there. Both support async code really well and will give you more performance.

Comment: It's just a turn based board game. I agree that if it was a realtime game like pingpong or something node.js would be better.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use [FAYE](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) which has Ruby Server and Node.js server, you can choose one